# Converting JSON to XML gives invalid XML

Tags: java, json, xml

I am trying to convert a valid JSON file to XML.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); 
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
String line = buf.readLine(); StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
while(line != null){ 
    sb.append(line); 
    line = buf.readLine(); 
} 

//form the string
String jsonStr = sb.toString();

//save to xml
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonStr);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

Here is my dependencies:

```
import org.json.XML;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

The input JSON is like this:

```
{"created":"2016-12-22T10:46:40.584Z","createdBy":"ish"}
```

The output XML looks like:

```
"{&quot;createdBy&quot;:&quot;ish&quot;,&quot;created&quot;:&quot;2016-12-22T10:46:40.584Z&quot;}"
```

Comment: `XML.toString(json);` What is this API ?

Comment: I am guessing that OP is using org.json.XML

Comment: @bhspencer Very probably. But where does `JSONParser` come from  ? The issue is probably related to a misuse of the used API. The OP should be clear about its dependencies.

Comment: @davidxxx i have added in my dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you mix two APIs : `json-simple` and `org.json`.
Here :

```
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

You pass a `org.json.simple.JSONObject` object to `the org.json.XML.toString(Object)` method.
What you want to pass is a `org.json.JSONObject`.
Actually, you don't need to use  `json-simple` as you can create a `JSONObject` with `org.json` and more particularly a  `org.json.JSONObject`.  Which finally is a very good thing as `XML.toString()` would produce the expected result with an instance of that.
So change your code such as :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

Optionally you can add the tag name of the enclosing element :

```
String xml = XML.toString(json, "foo");
```

---

Note that `XML.toString(Object)` is not necessary a very good designed API.
It accepts an `Object` as parameter and so relies on `instanceof` to apply the suitable processing.
The mapping to XML is done only if the parameter type belongs to some specific types : `org.json.JSONObject`, `org.json.JSONArray`, Java `array`.
And if it is not the case, a single thing is do : special characters are escaped such as `"`.   As a `org.json.simple.JSONObject` doesn't make part of the expected type, the `"` of the `JSONObject` parameter were kept and the escaping converted them to `&quot;`. Whereas the weird result you get :

```
"{&quot;createdBy&quot;:&quot;ish&quot;,&quot;created&quot;:&quot;2016-12-22T10:46:40.584Z&quot;}"
```